# Issue on jQuery mouseout on Bootstrap 3 Dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/PzKnS/4/) and let me know why the `.dropdown-menu` slide up on mouse over? as you can see I have a script as:

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').click(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(400);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(400)
    });

$(".dropdown-menu").mouseout(function(){
      $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp(400)
});
```

and I have a `.mouseout()` function on `.dropdown-menu` selector but as you can see the dropdown  menu slides up as soon as user mouse over on it! can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: try `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`

Comment: Thanks Arun, it is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

```
$(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp(400)
});
```

Comment: Great Thanks Arun just can you please also let me know why the mouseout is not working here?

Comment: @user3668817 the [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) event is fired when the mouse is moved from a parent element to a descendant element or to any other element, where as the [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) is not fired when the mouse is moved to a descendant element - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L2hRY/1/)